# Globally changing math line spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, line-spacing, displaystyle

In multiline formulas, I often find myself inserting extra vertical space (`\\[...]`) between lines (especially when there are many superscripts and subscripts).  I guess a certain amount of manual spacing will always be necessary, but if I could increase the default that would decrease the amount of fiddling necessary for many of my documents.

How can I increase line spacing in equations, leaving normal text unaffected?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The command is `\jot`. See  mathmode for further information: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The vertical space between the lines for all math expressions are controlled by the dimension `\jot`. (I know the name isn't very intuitiv).

Here an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \ddot{x}_1+\ddot{x}_2 &= u \\
 x(0) &= \dfrac{27}{4} 
\end{align}

\addtolength{\jot}{10pt}
\begin{align}
 \ddot{x}_1+\ddot{x}_2 &= u \\
 x(0) &= \dfrac{27}{4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]